# Every time I want to start Python IDLE, it just loads

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

when I click the key in the left down corner with a Windows logo and click IDLE (Python 3.6 32-bit) it loads (I can see the blue cicle) but IDLE doesn't open. I tried about ten times. Yesterday it worked fine. Same happens when I press the Windows key. I have Windows 10 and my computer is HP Compaq CQ2000. I don't think I did any changes to Python files on my computer since yesterday. How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try to uninstall and reinstall?

Comment: Thanks. I uninstalled and installed again and it works now.

Comment: Belongs on superuser.

Comment: You probably dragged it off your screen so that you couldn't see it, and it remembered where it was. To fix, type `Alt-Space` `M` (same as system menu, move) then use the arrow keys to try and get it into view.